# Using luarocks to distribute programs

Tags: lua, luarocks

luarocks is mainly used to distribute lua libraries which are then loaded using `require` in a script. I was wondering if it's possible to use luarocks to distribute executable programs written in Lua.

There seems to be no distinction made by luarocks, so everything installed ends up in `/usr/lib*`. Is there an easy way (for common user) to automatically install a program into `/usr/local/bin`, preferably without having to pass a special argument to luarocks?

Answer (score 2):

I have done a fast search by google using title of your topic as search string.

First result was this page ;-)

Second - http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2016-06/msg00139.html